# How to use a C union to equate multiple named variables and another, larger named variable?

Tags: c, vector, struct, sse, unions

Let's say I have a struct

```
struct vector_struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} vector;
```

I would like to be able to address the x, y, and z values as `vector.x` etc. which the above code allows me to do. However, in order to facilitate fast arithmetic with SSE SIMD instructions in an explicit way, I would like to do the following:

```
union vector_union {
    struct vector_struct float_values;
    __m128d packed_values;
} vector;
```

Now, if I want to do SIMD instructions on the vector, I can just use `vector.packed_values` as an argument to various SIMD instructions (like multiplication). However, this looks very ugly, as if I wanted the value of `x`, I would have to write

```
foo = vector.float_values.x
```

instead of just

```
foo = vector.x
```

So then, my question is if there is any way to make a `union` that associates *multiple named variables* with another *single named variable*. Something like

```
union vector_union {
    float values[3];
    __m128d packed_values;
} vector;
```

except where `vector.values[0]` can be referred to as `vector.x`, `vector.values[1]` can be referred to as `vector.y`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of C2011, you can use an anonymous struct member in your union,

```
union vector_union {
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
    };
    __m128d packed;
} vector;
```

and then you can use `vector.x` etc. to access the components, and `vector.packed_values` to use the SSE instructions. Note, however, that the standard doesn't guarantee that the `struct`member is packed. (But normally, the compiler will pack it.)

If the compiler doesn't support C2011, it may offer anonymous structs as an extension.

Comment: Excellent! I had no idea anonymous structs had been added! Thank you very much!